# Table rails_project.users doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have been trying to move my current rails application's db from sqlite to MYSQL.
I have made the changes in database.yml file. But its been many times I ran rake:db create and migrate, but nothing does not work for me.

I end up in the error stating "Table 'rails_project.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `users`".

My db name is rails_project and I am using devise authentication where the table name is users.

I am so frustrated with this issue.

Can anyone help me?

database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rails_project
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  host : localhost
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rails_project
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  host : localhost
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock     
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: rails_project
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  host : localhost
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

migrated file:

```
   class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""
```

Comment: add your database.yml content

Comment: Do you actually have a migration to create the users table?

Comment: you have all environments in the same db?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I have a migration named users.rb, but still I get the table exists error. I do not have any tables inside the database.

Comment: Can you post up the content of your migration named users.rb?

Answer (score 1):

This means that you are trying to use something before define its table, in my case I tried to use some code in factories.rb:

```
 Assesment.new.questions ...
```

So when I ran my code on travis during `rake db:schema:load` all code is interpreted and in that part it got same error, solution is:

- Avoid using a model before define its table
- Use lazy syntax wrapping with `{` and `}`, at least in FactoryGirl use

Just tried to read carefully log to see was line of your code is triggering the error